# Two instance take turns take from Hazelcast blocking queue, how to avoid read duplicate items as possible as we can

Tags: redis, message-queue, hazelcast, distributed-system

here some backgrounds:
we have several service instances sharing a Hazelcast blocking quque, the service mainly have two tasks:

1. There is a scheduler put items into the queue perdically, lets say every 5 mins put 100 items
2. Another class watching the queue, as long as it have any items it will start process (basically one item may take 1 to 2 seconds to process)

I have few questions about above solution:

1. **how to avoid add duplicate items to the queue in case any two instances run the scheduler at same time** (e.g. if the queue got 'A', 'B' in it, instanceA will put 'A', 'D', definitely it could filter out A because it in the queue, so instanceA will put D into the queur, in the meantime instanceB put D as well because it's local queue dont have the D at that moment)
2. **how to aovid instanceA and instanceB take duplicate item** (e.g. instance A take first item, but the queue not yet sycn to instance B, will the instance B take same first item as well?) we might dont need strictly avoid dumplicate item, but try to avoid as possible as we can.

edit by phone,  apologize if there was any spell problem. maybe the better solution is turn to redis or other centralize way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Hazelcast. But I know that Redis have the solution.

> 1. How to avoid duplicate items to the queue?

You can use `Redis Set` to store none duplicate items, before you push the item to redis message queue, just check if item exist in `Redis Set`, if existed, then quit the push operation.

> 2. How to avoid item to be taked duplicatedly?

You can use `Redis List` as the message queue, with the `rpop` atomic operation, instanceA and instanceB can not take duplicate item.